# Was bedeutet "die kurz davor stehen" im Kontext?

Tags: meaning-in-context

> Das Buch soll Aufmerksamkeit schaffen und Menschen anregen, über Zahlungsalternativen nachzudenken, **die** **kurz** **davor** **stehen**, Mainstream zu werden.

Meint man mit "die kurz davor stehen", dass einige Schritte fehlen, um zum Mainstream zu werden?

Comment: Einfacher formuliert *... nachzudenken, die kurz vor dem Durchbruch stehen.*.

Comment: @guidot Zwischen beiden Varianten würde ich einen klaren Unterschied sehen: Während 'Mainstream' auf etwas allgemein Gebräuchliches oder Akzeptiertes verweist, resultiert der 'Durchbruch' nur in einer Etablierung, im Sinne einer nach bestem Wissen dauerhaft gesicherten Existenz. Beispiel: Die Zahlungsalternative 'Kreditkarte' hatte ihren Durchbruch mit dem Erreichen einer bestimmten Schwelle von kooperierenden Geschäften, wurde zu diesem Zeitpunkt (auf den ich mich absichtlich nicht festlege) aber von der beschränkten Gruppe wohlhabender Konsumenten genutzt. Mainstream wurde sie erst mit der f

Comment: ... flächendeckenden Ausgabe an Girokunden.

Comment: @collapsar: Ich verstehe was du meinst, halte es aber für komplett offen, ob *Durchbruch* die Schwelle zur Machbarkeit, zur *dauerhaft gesicherten Existenz*, zum nenenswerten Marktanteil oder zum *Marktanteil > 50%* (um *Mainstream* versuchshalber zu definieren) bedeutet. Im letzteren Fall würde ich behaupten, dass sich in Deutschland der Mainstream noch auf absehbare Zeit im Bargeld erschöpft.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Einfach gesagt: Ja.
Die Zahlungsalternativen sind noch nicht Mainstream, da noch nicht genug Leute diese benutzen. Aber es ist abzusehen, dass diese bald im Mainstream ankommen, also von einer relevanten Masse genutzt werden.
Es mag in diesem speziellen Fall auch so sein, dass die Technologie zum Nutzen dieser Zahlungsalternativen noch nicht in jedem Geschäft verfügbar ist.